# Developer warning for package , Failed to post notification on channel "null" See log for more details

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to run this code here https://github.com/manjurulhoque/android-scheduler ,

but when I'm trying to send scheduled email msg, an error, toast msg appears:

> Developer warning for package "com.manjurulhoque.scheduler" Failed to
>   post notification on channel "null" See log for more details

I don't know where is the problem and I did not use notification channel before 
hope you help me please ):

thank you ...